# How can i get more info about a brew formula before installing?

Tags: homebrew

I know i can do something like

```
## brew info FORMULA_NAME
brew info wgetpaste
```

### Output

```
wgetpaste: stable 2.20
http://wgetpaste.zlin.dk/
Not installed
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/wgetpaste.rb
```

Then i can follow the url to get some info about the formula before installing. Do we have any way to get this info in command line using brew?

Comment: @SamarPanda - this site is about making beer and wine, not about the homebrew package manager project. I've migrated your question to SO.

Comment: @mdma Oh my bad. Thanks for migrating. I will take care in future so i don't do that.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `brew info` command's output now (as of 2022-ish) contains a brief description of what the formula installs. So it now probably already gives the info asked for here, though it didn't back in 2013 when this question was originally posted.

You can do a `brew home <formula>` to fire up a browser with the package's home page from the command line for more details. Or `brew edit <formula>` to examine the formula's installation instructions themselves in an editor.

You can also run `brew desc --eval-all <formula>` for a more concise one-line description of what the formula installs, without all the extra info about sources and dependencies and analytics.

Comment: This answer was true when it was written (in 2013), but it has not been true for a long time. Please see [the answer from Paul Crook in this same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598930/26702) for the current best answer.

Comment: Andrew, please edit this to acknowledge `brew desc`, which is now part of homebrew.

Comment: 2024 - I still find this answer useful, because I like the command to open up the webpage of the formula. 
a) brew info [--cask] <formula> -> for info in the terminal
b) brew home <formula> -> for getting the info in the browser. But as @Telemachus said, it could be added to the answer, because the answer is the accepted and top voted answer.

Comment: Oof. I'm not sure I like this SO "edit someone else's answer" feature. I just spent twenty minutes figuring out how I should respond to Kai's comment here when it seemed like I already covered that in the answer, to eventually notice that it's bc Telemachus changed my answer to include `brew desc`. And now I've got my name as the main author of some text I didn't actually write. Hmmm.

Comment: Anyway. I'm not sure I like putting the `brew desc` thing at the top here, because IMHO that's not "more info" like OP is asking for; it's just a more-concise presentation of selected info that's already in the `brew info` output. I think `brew home` is still a more direct answer to OP's question.

Comment: I edited the answer to move the `brew desc` to the bottom, bc I don't want it to look like I was suggesting `brew desc` as "*more* info". Open to further discussion here.

Comment: Ah, I think I see: looks like a few years ago, `brew info` didn't include this info, so `brew desc` did give more info, but now the contents of `brew desc` are also displayed in `brew info`. I edited my answer again to reflect that.

Answer (score 29):

You can get a one-line textual description of a package with:

```
brew desc FORMULA-NAME
```

For example, "brew desc terminator" returns:

terminator: Multiple terminals in one window

In Homebrew 3.6 you will see this message:

`Warning: Calling brew desc is deprecated! Use brew desc --eval-all or HOMEBREW_EVAL_ALL instead.`

Comment: This is probably the most correct answer to this question, at this time.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
brew cask info [package]
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `brew [cask] cat [...]` to see the exact formula (without necessarily editing it as other answers here suggest). It shows what gets downloaded, from where, with what checksum, what other formuli/casks it depends on, etc. Here's an example:

```
$ brew cask cat java
cask 'java' do
  version '12.0.2,10:e482c34c86bd4bf8b56c0b35558996b9'
  sha256 '675a739ab89b28a8db89510f87cb2ec3206ec6662fb4b4996264c16c72cdd2a1'

  url "https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk#{version.before_comma}/#{version.after_colon}/#{version.after_comma.before_colon}/GPL/openjdk-#{version.before_comma}_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz"
  name 'OpenJDK Java Development Kit'
  homepage 'https://openjdk.java.net/'

  artifact "jdk-#{version.before_comma}.jdk", target: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-#{version.before_comma}.jdk"

  uninstall rmdir: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In homebrew you have casks and formulas, which have different functions, so:

**For formulas:**

To get info about the formula itself you can use what you did (`brew info [formula name`). 
To get info about the app you're installing use:

```
brew desc [Formula name]
```

You can also go to the homebrew's site for the formula via `brew home [formula name`

**For Casks:**

Sadly, casks (like Firefox) don't have the `desc` command and you only have `brew cask info` (what you used) and `brew cask home`

Answer (score 1):

Works as of January 2024 with Homebrew 4.1.1:

`brew info --cask <packagename>`