# How to see available options for homebrew formula install?

Tags: homebrew, libxml2

I'm reading this stack overflow answer

[Mac user and getting WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802410/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-8-but-has-dynamically-lo/14658949#answer-10912948)

and I just want to know where they learned about the `--with-xml2-config` option in

```
brew install libxml2 --with-xml2-config
```

so that I can verify I really want to use this option myself and so I can better solve problems with homebrew myself in the future.

How can I see a description of this specific option and, more generally, find out all the available options for a formula when using brew install?

I know `brew info FORMULA` gets me some stuff like that, but `brew info libxml2` only lists the options `--universal`, `--without-python`, and `--HEAD`.

For more info, here is another stack overflow question that is similar to this one but different: [How can i get more info about a brew formula before installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860297/how-can-i-get-more-info-about-a-brew-formula-before-installing)

Comment: The obvious answer would be to read the formula itself, they're reasonably readable even without previous exposure to Ruby. For example https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/18cd018cc5a2ea8b30f291e34628ffd8ce211f68/Library/Formula/libxml2.rb .

Comment: Where in that file are the available options to `brew install FORMULA` listed? ...Oh, I see `option :universal`, `build.universal?`, `build.head?`, and `build.with? 'python'`. Maybe those hint at the available options. So is `--with-xml2-config` not a real option for `brew install libxml2`?

Comment: Last I checked I don't think I was able to find good documentation for the ruby brew file. That would be a good addition to this page if anyone finds it.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `options` first to check:

```
brew options libxml2
```

If this dose not satisfy you, edit the rb file directly, and do whatever you want to:

```
brew edit libxml2
```

Comment: It appears all options have been removed from `homebrew-core` : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510

Answer (score 1):

you can often see available options in the `.rb` brew file. Open with your favorite text editor, they usually live here on MacOS:

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/`

you can apply arguments in the files too, like `--enable-foo`

these files don't usually contain "descriptions" however

Answer (score -2):

`brew install` ignores any options it does not recognize.  `--with-xml2-config` is not a real option of the `libxml2` formula; it just gets ignored.

Comment: Sounds good. Just curious, what's your source? Have you worked on Homebrew itself? Did you read this somewhere?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question; simply explains how to verify if an options is valid, not to find all all the valid options.

Comment: It answers the first part of the question: "How can I see a description of this specific option ..."

Comment: I don't think it ignores. I am getting `Error: invalid option: --with-graphviz` with `doxygen --with-graphviz --with-qt --with-llvm`